# How to solve the system of matrix equations $XX^TA = A$, $X^TX = I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, stiefel-manifolds

Given tall matrix $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$ (where $n \gg k$), is there a way to solve the following system of matrix equations in $X \in \mathbb R^{n \times k}$?

$$\begin{aligned} X X^T A &= A\\ X^T X &= I_k\end{aligned}$$

Matrix $A$ is probably of rank $k$.

Comment: Where does this system come from? Something Procrustes-like?

Comment: For the case $n = k$, the set of solutions would be all orthogonal matrices $X$. This is already a lot of solutions, so I don't think you will get a unique $X$ even when increasing $n$ in general. What you can do is write down the quadratic equations you get for the entries of $X$ and try to solve this system. Again, I think that in general, you will get a lot of solutions without a nice structure.

Comment: It from an optimization problem.
$$
\begin{array}{c}{\min _{X}\|X-A\|_{F}^{2}} \\ {\text { s.t. } \quad X^{T} X=I}\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Dirk Thanks. I will think about it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the link. However, $X$ is not an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: @YouweiLiang I don't think it's a problem. See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333493/find-a-matrix-with-orthonormal-columns-with-minimal-frobenius-distance-to-a-give

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks. You are right.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments posted by @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, we can do the SVD $\mathbf A = \mathbf{USV}^\top$, then set $\mathbf X = \mathbf U \mathbf V^\top$. It is easy to check that it is indeed a solution.
$$
\mathbf X^\top\mathbf X = \mathbf V \mathbf U^\top \mathbf U \mathbf V^\top = \mathbf I
$$
$$
\mathbf{XX}^\top \mathbf A = \mathbf{UV}^\top \mathbf{VU}^\top \mathbf{USV}^\top = \mathbf{USV}^\top = \mathbf A
$$

Comment: If it is the singular value decomposition, how could the multiplication $UV^T$ be possible? The $U$ should be $n\times n$ matrix, and $V$ be $k\times k$.

Comment: @WenkueiP'ei Because we have the “economy” or “reduced” version of the SVD, we can drop the zeros in the diagonal of $S$ and drop some columns in $U$ or $V$. See page 2 in [this note](https://www.math.muni.cz/~zelinka/cjh/svd.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The optimization problem you posted in the comment is minimizing the Euclidean norm on the space of matrices of given form.

Now the entries of $X^TX$ are polynomials of total degree two in the entries of $X$, so you have a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n \cdot k}$ given by polynomial equations, this is relatively nice and you should be able to get lots of properties of this set.

There are lots of results on how to find the distance between a set and a given point in an Euclidean space. Thus, I think going down this road will give you better results than trying to solve the matrix equation.

Answer (score 0):

From $X^TX = I$, we know that the matrix $X$ has $k$ mutually orthogonal bases. Also, the matrix $A$ has $k$ vectors maybe linearly independent.

To minimize the distance between the two sets of vectors, since the length of the column vectors of $X$ is 1, the spanning space of column vectors of $X$ should be the same as $A$.

Thus there exists a $k \times k$ invertible matrix $H$, makes $X = AH$, and $X - A = AH - A$, which lefts $H$ to optimization for:
$$
\min_{H} \| AH - A\|_F^2
$$
with the constraint $AH^THA^T = I$. The whole thing might become easier for the Lagrange multiplier method and further numerical optimization.